# Ubuntu Err :18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg KEYEXPIRED 1555048520

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Since this morning I have this error

> Err :18 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
>     The following signatures are not valid : KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520  KEYEXPIRED 1555048520

when I'm running

> sudo apt-get update -y

I searched some solutions but I didn't find the good one on google so ... I'm here

Comment: Apparently, google's signing key expired, so we just need to wait until they put out a new one. After they did just run `wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -` to fix your problem.

Comment: I still have the problem

Comment: Did you read my comment? You have to wait until google puts out a new signing key. Until they do it, there is nothing we can do about the problem.

Comment: most probably the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133199/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-expkeysig-1397bc53640db551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ongoing problem that only seems to hit Google Chrome. In order to avoid seeing warnings, one can temporarily turn off the repository for GC.

Comment: Seeing this happen today as well. Disabling the repository may work, as Google Chrome can update itself. If it can't, it will show an icon for you to start the update.

Answer (score 3):

`wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -`

https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/

Comment: I still have the error ... :/

Comment: this is first what I've tried and it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Just wait until google updates their signing key. This is not going to help before they do.

Comment: Must wait Google update there singing key and then do this command. It will be later today I think.

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the problem (temporary) use --allow-unauthenticated in the apt command and wait until google fix the signing key.

You can check it from time to time by calling

```
curl 'https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub' | gpg
```